# Using text from clipboard. Python 3

Tags: python, text, clipboard

I'm writing a small program in python that copies text from a CAD-program and then creates a XML-file based on the text.

I've encountered a problem. Neither tkinter's root.clipboard_get() nor pyperclips.paste() give the same (correct) result as pasting manually with Ctrl+V into notepad. Some lines of text is missing for whatever strange reason. I can't seem to find a way around this and to me it looks like my best option (although very stupid) is to write something that:

1. Copy text from CAD-program
2. Create new .txt file and paste from clipboard
3. Copy text from .txt file
4. Delete .txt file
5. Use the copied text from step 3 in the program

So far I've got:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
clip = root.clipboard_get()
f = open('cliptext.txt', 'w')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
f.close()
clip2 = root.clipboard_get()
```

I'm still new to python and very lost so all help is highly appreciated!

Comment: What 'certain text' doesn't get copied, maybe unescaped symbols

Comment: EDIT: I can't get linebreaks to work so this is the best I can do, each code-box is on a seperate line.
This is what root.clipboard_get() and pyperclip.paste gives:

    `-B114 UK`
    `2`
    `4-K-22.6-0004`
    `ÖK+UK`
    `6Ø12-FL`


And this is what Ctrl+V in notepad gives:

    `1Ø12`
    `-B114 UK`
    `2`
    `1+1Ø12-F102`
    `JMF./COMPARE`
    `4-K-22.6-0004`
    `1+1Ø12`
    `-F102`
    `ÖK+UK`
    `6Ø12-FL`

Comment: you can use .rstrip() on a string to remove all trailing newlines

Comment: Oh, I meant I cant get linebreaks to work here in the comments on stackoverflow.

Comment: so both methods are consistently returning the same text?

Comment: Yeah, I dont really see a pattern of which lines will be excluded. In the CAD-program the text is written on different layers, fonts and so on. But I find it really strange because Ctrl+V gives the correct answer so it should be in the clipboard somewhere.

Comment: have you tried using any other libraries for clipboar